Is there any user-friendly software to extract the metadata from an emailed picture to show the date it was taken?
I have tried everything I could find in researching this, nothing works. I just want to find out the date some pictures that were emailed to me as attachments were taken. I tried several EXIF programs to no avail-- they just show the date the pictures were accessed and shared (i.e. today). I tried saving the images to files and looking at the Details-- no help at all. I use windows 10 and have an Android phone (so all the threads about how an iPhone does it are useless to me). I do know that the photos were themselves taken with a phone camera.
I am not a computer whiz, so anything requiring complicated command line knowledge is not helpful. I would even be happy to pay someone to do this for me if that's what it takes.

https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ Is a better site for this question.

There is no guarantee that the files contain this information. It can be removed easily, or indeed not recorded at all to begin with (e.g. some phones and camera apps have privacy settings whereby Exif data is not recorded). The fact you received the files by email is no guarantee that they have full Exif data.

It takes special effort to edit/filter an image but keep EXIF data like the original shooting date.  Is it possible these pics just went through a filter, or were resized into a new smaller file by the messaging app? If an EXIF program is showing the wrong values it's probably because the EXIF values are wrong.

Even if you can read EXIF data, there is no guarantee it hasn't been altered after the image was shot. There's no way to know if EXIF info is true or not. (Well, I guess if it says the image was taken in the future you'd KNOW it was forged...}

This appears to be an X→Y question. What you really want to know is how to find out when an image was taken by using the info in the image file. We have existing questions that cover this. In a nutshell, the answer is that you can't, because EXIF info can be forged/edited in a way that looks no different if the image was taken at a different time than if the image was taken at the time the EXIF info says it was.

Ok, I get that apparently the EXIF data can be forged/edited/stripped, so you never know if what you're seeing is true, but WHY would anyone do that? Personally, I never even knew this was a possibility. I seriously doubt the person who sent these pics to me even had the know-how or wherewithal to go to that effort, either.  I'm more prone to believe their phone app stripped the data out of privacy settings or resizing. I don't know how to tell.

Images browsers (XnView or IrfanView for instance) will display EXIF data if they are present.
But their presence is far from guaranteed:

Very often sharing via phone apps strips most of the EXIF data for privacy purposes. Usually this also comes together with an image downscale to save network bandwidth, so the file size (in bytes and in pixels) is a a good clue that the image has been reprocessed.
The EXIF data can have been stripped intentionally
As far as I can tell sharing by GoogleMail from an Android phone sends the image from the phone without altering it, but it won't reinstate EXIF data that have been stripped earlier. If you are forwarded by mail an image that comes from WhatsApp, it won't have more data than what WhatsApp shares.


I downloaded and tried both of these as well, but I guess part of the problem is I don't know how exactly I am supposed to get the picture from the email into the software. I have, of course, done 'Save Image As' and saved them as jpg files on my hard drive, but when I put those into the EXIF program, it just shows today's date for File Creation.

You have done it right, so there is no such meta data in these images.

If you are on Windows, assuming a JPEG, then Right-Click⇾Properties⇾Details tab and if there isn't a date/time listed under "Date Taken", then the metadata has been stripped away and there isn't any way to recover it.

Must not be a regular jpeg, because that's not even an option. What I see when I r-click on it is this: https://i.imgur.com/aqI7GXx.jpg

@K.L.R. it looks like you're viewing it in your browser, try right clicking on the file instead.

I am not sure what you mean "clicking on the file instead". These are pictures attached to an email.

You can't find out anything about the file when it is in your browser. You need to select the "Save to File" option and save it to your desktop. You would then Right-Click the file and select Properties. Then select the Details tab and you will see something like this. If there is a time stamp in the file, it will appear on the "Date Taken" line. If nothing appears there, then there isn't any metadata for the date/time in the file.

I can r-click on the pictures but I do not see a "Save to File" option; there is a "Save Image As" option, which allows me to save it as a jpg. Is that what you mean? If I do that, then go to the file and look at Details > Origin > Date Taken, there is nothing there, it looks like this:  https://i.imgur.com/rM6zlUI.jpg

Yes, and that shows that my answer is correct. There is no metadata in the image. It has been stripped away.
